# AngularJs 1.5 - unable to communicate between two components via parent component

Tags: angularjs-components

I have 3 components in the following order: 1 parent component with 2 child components. I need to run a function within the parent component, by initiating it from either of the two child components.

Both child components `js` file looks like this:

```
angular
    .module('app)
    .component(childComponent1, {
        bindings: {
            switch: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {    
        }]
    });

angular
    .module('app)
    .component(childComponent2, {
        bindings: {
            switch: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {    
        }]
    });
```

Parent component:

```
angular
    .module('app)
    .component(parentComponent, {
        bindings: {
            switch: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
           this.switch = function(){
               'some code...'
            }
        }]
    });
```

In each child component template there's a button which should run the parent function `switch`, like so:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="$ctrl.switch()">Back</button>
```

The code does not work, any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using bindings try using the required param in the children in order to access the parent component controller.

```
require: {
   parentCtrl: '^parentComponent'
},
```

Have a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/fPGuZzIqNbfXeBGXve4J?p=preview for an example of this approach.

Also, if using .component to try and make your Angular 1.5 more easily upgradable to Angular 2.0 you should also try and avoid the use of $scope in your component controllers.